# How to setup portable shared folders in vbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to set up a vbox image that will be distributed to several people with several different types of OS.  Namely, microsoft, apple and Linux.

I want some folders to be shared between host machine and virtual machine, however vbox asks for an absolute path to the shared folder on the host.  How do I supply a path relative to the current users home directory, like `~user` in Linux, so that the image is more portable across platforms?

With absolute paths, I will need to tell all users of the vbox image to manually reconfigure the shared folder path, which I would prefer to avoid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Here is request for this feature: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15305